# ANGULAR Modular Fédération - Why Mfe1 app.module.ts(root module) not able to configure in webpack instead of specific modules

Tags: angular, webpack, micro-frontend, modular

I tried in webpack.config.ts:
instead of

```
exposes: {
'./Module': './projects/mfe1/src/app/users/users.module.ts',
},
```

replaced with

```
exposes: {
"./Module": "./projects/mfe1/src/app/app.module.ts",
},
```

In app.routes.ts at main shell:

```
{
    path: 'users',
    loadChildren: () =>
      loadRemoteModule({
        type: 'manifest',
        remoteName: 'mfe1',
        exposedModule: './Module'
      }).then((m) => m.UsersModule), // m.AppModule
}
```

accessing in the main application, but i get as shown screenshot error?

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.
Error: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@SaKol, now your imports for UsersModulelooks so?

```js
 @NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    ...
]

Remove BrowserModule from UsersModule imports. 
 @NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
    ...
]
```

Try to remove BrowserModule from your new mfe module.
I reproduced same error in my app (which use module federation)
[image]

Comment: No, it not worked already in my project removed the (browserModule) import on User module of mfe1 project please find the screenshot above

Comment: try to delete BrowserModule from others mfe-s... except shell...
try this command: 
nx clear-cache or nx reset

Comment: Tried removing the browser module on mfe1 and mfe2 app module, I get
'forRoot' is used outside of the injector. Lazy loaded modules should be use RouterModule.forChild()

Comment: For @Eugene_Kr, referance provind the sample example its public repo you can have a look (https://github.com/Sakol538/MFe_Flights_module)

Comment: @SaKol not sure what you want to do... how you want to organise the architecture.
But if you want just to load this component make such changes: 



projects/shell/src/app/app.component.html

line 4:  
<li><a routerLink="/flights-search">Flights</a></li>

projects/shell/src/app/app.routes.ts 
line 22-25:
 {
    path: 'flights-search',
    component: FlightsSearchComponent,
  },

Comment: But I guess you are trying to achive something other...  if you want to load this module and show component you should update your mfe1 module - first you must to load it(mfe1) instead of FlightsModule. So go into shell app.routes and define in  routes per component load mfe1 on navigating to flights (mfe1/src/app/app.module). to load actual FlightsModule & Component via Mfe module you should in this Mfe1 AppModule define the routes structure -  to guide angular routing into the correct Component.

Comment: @SaKol ah ok now I see same message. So Navigate to webpack config and change shareAll method to share
Pls consult the docs (sometimes it want work as expected)
change shareAll to share and place next code(pls add other deps if required)

Comment: shared:share( {'@angular/core': {singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto'},'@angular/common': {singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto'},                        '@angular/common/http': {singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto'},                   '@angular/router': {singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto'},
'@angular/platform-browser': {singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto'}  }   })

Comment: https://github.com/EugeneKruglei/solution
get it work

Comment: Thanks for responding and show intrest on resolving the problem appriciative
but I tried above  repository (github.com/EugeneKruglei/solution)
Getting the run time error at: Error: Shared module is not available for eager consumption: 1327

Comment: https://github.com/EugeneKruglei/solution/issues/1

Comment: hm it's strange, try to use your config for shared modules. It seems that mistake was in module loading & routing.

Comment: Hey @SaKol, sorry for long reply - I updated/reverted back webpack config

Comment: not resolved, closed ticket @Eugene_Kr

Comment: what is not resolved? It works

Comment: how we can access app components after injecting AppModule